# Eliminate key lookup in execution plan

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, performance, execution-plan, query-performance

I have the following query:

```
DECLARE @p__linq__0 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

SET @p__linq__0 = '... some guid ...'

SELECT TOP 1
    [EventId] AS [EventId],       
    [DateCreated] AS [DateCreated],       
    [LocationId] AS [LocationId],       
    [SourceName] AS [SourceName],       
    [SourceState] AS [SourceState],       
    [Priority] AS [Priority],       
    [EventDescription] AS [EventDescription],       
    [FirstTrigger] AS [FirstTrigger]
FROM [dbo].[Watchdog]
WHERE 
    [LocationId] = @p__linq__0
    AND 
    [FirstTrigger] = 1
ORDER BY [DateCreated] DESC
```

`Watchdog` table defines 2 indecies:

1. Clustered index on `EventId` primary key column
2. Unclustered index on `DateCreated` column

This is actual execution plan for the query:
[image]

Reading [other posts](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/183006/eliminate-key-lookup-clustered-operator-that-slows-down-performance) on how to eliminate key lookup I added another non-clustered index which includes all columns from `SELECT`

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [LocationId_FirstTrigger] ON [dbo].[Watchdog]
(
    [LocationId] ASC,
    [FirstTrigger] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [EventId],
    [DateCreated],
    [SourceName],
    [SourceState],
    [Priority],
    [EventDescription]) WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

However, this didn't help and actual execution plan is the same. If I look at key lookup the output is actually included in newly added non clustered index.

[image]

My question is, why it's still doing `key lookup` instead of index scan/seek ?

---

**UPDATE**

Following some suggestions in the comments, I dropped newly created non clustered index & instead recreated non clustered index on `DateCreated` column including columns from `SELECT`.

Now execution plan is the following:

[image]

Also query execution time dropped from 1+ minute to few seconds (this table has 18+ million rows).

Does this mean key lookup was done due to `ORDER BY` on non-clustered index ?

Comment: Maybe a hint: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/222987/why-would-optimiser-choose-clustered-index-sort-instead-of-non-clustered-index

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> My question is, why it's still doing key lookup instead of index scan/seek ?

The query specifies that results should be ordered by `DateCreated`.  Since you already had a nonclustered index on `DateCreated`, the optimizer decided that the cost of doing key lookups was lower than sorting all of the data by `DateCreated`.

> Does this mean key lookup was done due to ORDER BY on non-clustered index ?

Essentially, yes.  It was estimated to be cheaper* to read the data in the required order, and get any additional fields through a key lookup, rather than reading all of the fields from a single index and then sorting it by `DateCreated`.

You could confirm this by comparing the estimated costs between

- the original query (with the original indexes), and
- the original query with an index hint

The index hint would be like this on the `FROM` line:

```
FROM [dbo].[Watchdog] WITH (INDEX (LocationId_FirstTrigger))
```

This should produce a plan with no key lookups (since `LocationId_FirstTrigger` is covering for that query), and a `Sort` operator.  I'd expect the "Estimated Cost" to be higher, thus the other plan was chosen.

---

* To explain the optimizer's choice here:

The `TOP (1)` in your query means the optimizer sets a [row goal](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/24832), meaning the plan is geared toward producing one row quickly. The optimizer expects to find one row from the *Index Scan* matching your `LocationId` predicate very quickly, since it assumes values are distributed uniformly. This may or may not be true in reality. The cost of one *Key Lookup* following the *Index Scan* is pretty small.

The scan + lookup option therefore looks cheaper to the optimizer than finding matches using `LocationId_FirstTrigger` and sorting. You can turn the row goal logic off for the query as a test by adding an `OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 4138)` hint. You will likely find the optimizer then chooses the `LocationId_FirstTrigger` index without an index hint.

Still, the best alternative is to modify your index [as Mikael Eriksson suggests](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/246661).

Answer (score 7):

You should move the column `DateCreated` to the key columns in the index `LocationId_FirstTrigger`.

Then you will get a seek on `LocationId` and `FirstTrigger` and a backward scan of the index to locate the row with highest value of `DateCreated` according to `select top(1) ... order by DateCreated desc`.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [LocationId_FirstTrigger] ON [dbo].[Watchdog]
(
    [LocationId] ASC,
    [FirstTrigger] ASC,
    [DateCreated]
)
INCLUDE (   
    [EventId],
    [SourceName],
    [SourceState],
    [Priority],
    [EventDescription]) WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
```

If the index is not ordered by `DateCreated` SQL Server will have to read all matching rows and sort them to know what row to return.